# fixed position text and image in Shopify

Tags: html, css, shopify, shopify-template

I am trying to add text in the corners that would be always visible with an image in the middle but cannot find any examples online, any help please?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOfjh.png)

Comment: Hi! do you want this section sticky or just center align text with the image?

Comment: If by sticky you mean fixed position and stays always visible then yes both.

Answer (score 1):

```css
 body{   
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
    .out{
    min-height: 600px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.out_div {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: fixed;
   background-color:red;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 99;

}
    .img img {
        max-width: 50px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="out">
    <div class="out_div">
    <div class="content">shop</div>
    <div class="img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300"></div>
    <div class="content">shop</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! Yet how to make it always visible on the page - fixed position? And how to add it to a shopify theme? Any ideas?

Comment: Please check this edited code.

Comment: Please visit this link to know more how to add sections in shopify  https://www.tech-prastish.com/blog/how-to-create-custom-sections-in-shopify/